# Need a version of _.where that includes the parent object key

Tags: lodash

What I have is an object like this:

```
formData = {
  name: {
    value: '',
    valid: true
  },
  zip: {
    value: 'ff',
    valid: false
  },
  //...
}
```

And I want to filter this so that I only have the invalid objects. The problem with `_.where` and `_.filter` is that it returns an object like this:

```
[
  0: {
    value: '',
    valid: false
  },
  1: {
    value: '',
    valid: false
  }
]
```

I need the parent key names, `name` and `zip` to be included. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for _.pick() my friend.
https://lodash.com/docs#pick

```
_.pick(formData, function(value) {
    return value.valid;
})
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you! It's really tough to find what you need in the documentation for both lodash and underscore.